# Getting Build error when i try to upload project to varcel

Tags: reactjs, next.js, vercel

Sorry i deleted my previous post becasue the image name and name when imported was different.
I fixed the issue but im still getting

```
ModuleNotFoundError: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../../public/assets/images/banner/bannerimg2.png' in '/vercel/1aa39631/containers/banner'


import React from 'react';
import { Container, Row, Col } from 'reactstrap';
import {Button} from '../../components/common/button';
import { Titlespan, Description } from '../../components/common/title/index';
import Image from '../../components/common/image/index';
import BannerImg1 from '../../public/assets/images/banner/bannerimg2.png';
import BannerBackgroundImages from '../../data/bannerimages';
import Shape2 from '../../public/assets/images/banner/bg-wave.svg';
import Shape3 from '../../public/assets/images/banner/wave.png';
import './banner.scss';
```

Answer (score 0):

The `public` (stays in the project root) folder is a special folder for storing static files (images, css, fonts)

You can embed these static files from the public folder in common elements: `<img src=...`, `<link href=...`

For example

```
public
  static
    images
      logo.png
    css
      custom.css

// In your components, remove the "public", use the child path
<img src="/static/images/logo.png />
<link href="/static/css/custom.css />
```

See https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/static-file-serving for more details

In your case, you want to import the SVG files, let's move them to another folder that's different with that `public` folder and change the old import paths